# Data structure to work well with versioned string data?

Tags: c, data-structures

What are "versioned data structures" called correctly in CS?

Is there some
list of existing "versioned data structures" somewhere that I could go through, compare and choose from on my own? I have found only one paper for "Multiple Version Hash Table" (title [Hash Tables in Logic Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.6833&rep=rep1&type=pdf), from circa 1987) and that's all I could find.

Sample data (requested in discussion below):

```
"a b" c "d e" {
    f {
        "g h" "i j" {
            "k l m" n "o p q" {
                r;
            }
        }
    }
}
"a b" x {
     y {
         "z z z";
     }
}
"foo bar" baz;
"foo baz" bar;
```

If multiple similar "trees" occur, then they will stay in place, like:

```
foo {
    bar;
    oof;
    bar {
       "a b c";
    }
    bar;
}
```

will never get sorted but always stay in the same order as written.

Data will be "compiled" into binary form by some "commit/version" tool and  "rolled back" back to text form or queried by another tools.

To clarify more, let's see some usage examples in Unix shell:

```
sh> $EDITOR file.txt
File saved.

sh> commit file.txt                      # create/commit file.txt.db (we assume 9 commits before this one)
Commited as version 10.

sh> show file.txt.db 'a b'               # Trailing '*' is implicit
"a b" c "d e" {
    f {
        "g h" "i j" {
            "k l m" n "o p q" {
                r;
            }
        }
    }
}
"a b" x {
     y {
         "z z z";
     }
}

sh> show file.txt.db 'a b' '*' y
"a b" x {
     y {
         "z z z";
     }
}

sh> show file.txt.db 'foo *'
"foo bar" baz;
"foo baz" bar;

sh> show file.txt.db -rollback=2 'a b'  # "historical" query, say that 'a b" c "d e" ...' was not there the time
"a b" x {
     y {
         "z z z";
     }
}

sh> rollback file.txt.db 2
Rolled back to version 2.

sh> $EDITOR file.txt
File saved.

sh> commit file.txt                      # new "branch" commit (because of the rollback above)!
Commited as version 2.1.
```

Note: ALL history is always saved! Nothing is going to be erased (if not explicitely requested by some other tool or so).

Etc. Perhaps some "log" or "journal" needed??

Comment: A quick Google search yields this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4282 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024739/java-versioned-data-structures

Comment: There are actually multiple types of "versioned data structures".  One might be having a binary ABI with backwards compatibility to older versions with different structures.  Another would be a datastructure where you can see access older versions of memory.  Knowing what you were trying to achieve would be helpful.  Some problems might be best solved externally (eg change log) to the data structure.

Comment: Well. I need to store and version tree-like data where any node is either a list of strings or a list of strings ending with a sub-tree, like this short example: `"a b" c "d e" { f { "g h" "i j" { "k l m" n "o p q" { r; } } } }; "a b" x { y { "z z z"; } }; etc.`. The point is it can also match from left one to each other, so I guess the task would best fit something like "multiversion trie" if something like that exists.

Comment: The goal is to provide "commit" and "rollback" operations on the data and fast lookups/pattern matching and comparison with any older version of certain branch of the tree, list it's "history" etc. Data will be in plain text file and the utility will generate and operate on binary database made from the text data.

Comment: I suggest putting your clarifications into your question - which should make it easier for us to understand the tree notation you are using.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, exactly, the "Hash Tables in Logic Programming"

Comment: @Jonathan: Is the clarification OK now?

Comment: I've placed the link to Hash Tables in your article - and removed my comment.  When you've found something, it is helpful to give people links to it so they don't necessarily have to redo your search.  The sequence of commands is interesting - but I'm not sure I understand what the outputs would be.  In particular, I'm not sure how I see versions of the trees, or how the `-rollback=3` option works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with purely text-based data, a basic versioned data structure could be as simple as an array or linked list of structures looking something like:

```
struct versioned_string {
    int   version;
    char* data;
};
```

"Committing" a new entry would only involve allocating a new string to store the data in.  Retrieving a specific version would involve walking the list looking for a particular `version` value (for a linked list) or indexing into the array (for an array).  A "rollback" would involve clearing out an entry from the end of the list and freeing the associated string.

You could also use a database (sqlite, for instance), store the information in a table, and let the DB engine handle the adds, deletes, and searches.  This might be overkill, however.

I don't really follow your example, though.  I'm assuming the first code block you posted indicates a single input string (that is, a snapshot of what the text data looks like at a particular version)?  If so, multiple "trees" shouldn't be a problem since the input is stored as raw text and not processed or interpreted in any way.  I certainly don't understand your "Unix shell" example.  Can you break that down in more detail?  Specifically, for each line, clearly list what the input is, what the output is, and what you expect the "current version" of the data to look like at that point.

**Update:**
Ignore my previous comment about rollback; I was thinking of it in terms of how this website uses the term (meaning to revert to a previous state), and you use the term differently (meaning to retrieve an older version).

Each snapshot of the entire data set can be represented by a single C string since elements are separated by non-null characters (whitespace and/or curly braces).  A simple data structure like the one I outlined above should give you the capabilities that you need if you create a linked list of them.  Since the data is stored in it's string representation, commit and rollback operations would be as trivial as adding a new element to the list (for commit) or walking the list backwards and passing the string to `printf` (for rollback).  The 'show' command is a different animal, because it doesn't really have much to do with the way you version the data.  As far as the versioning system is concerned, all you would do is grab the last entry from the list.  The real work there is done by whatever library functions you've created for parsing strings and manipulating data internally.

Comment: I thought it's pretty clear from the sample input and example usage. The records are lists of strings. In fact, every node consists of list of string and optionaly a sub-tree (delimited with `{` and `}`). The quatation marks (`"`) surround strings where blank character is present. So you have element `word` or `"a string"` (both of type string, of course).

Comment: Three utilities exists: a) `commit` that takes a textual input and either create a new dabatase or place new version (differences on elemental basis) from the last stored version of the data. b) `rollback` that (re-)creates text file from the database data some N steps back from the history (but still keeping the newer stored data!) and finally c) `show` command that queries the database using patterns that can be placed in positions of elements.

Comment: @mjf- In your shell example, you have the line `show file.txt.db 'a b'`.  Is `'a b'` the output or part of the input?  If it's not the output, what would the expected output be?  I'm assuming the input file in the `commit file.txt` line is the first code block that you posted?