# java: libraries for immutable functional-style data structures

Tags: java, data-structures, functional-programming

This is very similar to another question ([Functional Data Structures in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683430/functional-data-structures-in-java)) but the answers there are not particularly useful.

I need to use immutable versions of the standard Java collections (e.g. HashMap / TreeMap / ArrayList / LinkedList / HashSet / TreeSet). By "immutable" I mean immutable in the functional sense (e.g. [purely functional data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional)), where updating operations on the data structure do not change the original data, but instead return a new instance of the same kind of data structure. Also typically new and old instances of the data structure will share immutable data to be efficient in time and space.

From what I can tell my options include:

- [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/)
- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)
- [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)

but I'm not sure whether any of these are particularly appealing to me. I have a few requirements/desirements:

- **the collections in question should be usable directly in Java** (with the appropriate libraries in the classpath). FJ would work for me; I'm not sure if I can use Scala's or Clojure's data structures in Java w/o having to use the compilers/interpreters from those languages and w/o having to write Scala or Clojure code.
- **Core operations on lists/maps/sets should be possible w/o having to create function objects with confusing syntaxes** (FJ looks slightly iffy)
- **They should be efficient in time and space.** I'm looking for a library which ideally has done some performance testing. FJ's [TreeMap](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.22/javadoc/index.html) is based on a red-black tree, not sure how that rates.
- **Documentation / tutorials should be good enough so someone can get started quickly using the data structures.** FJ fails on that front.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is also https://github.com/blackdrag/pcollections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me you already know what your options are, you just aren't happy with any of them.  Here is my take on the three choices you've provided:

**Functional Java** - This one seems like the best fit for you.  It fits all of your requirements except that you don't like the documentation.  From my perspective the documentation looks basic, but serviceable.  Their [code snippets](http://functionaljava.org/examples/1.5/) should get you up and running quickly. The learning curve seems almost non-existent which should help mitigate the lack of documentation. FYI, core Java's [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is based on a Red-Black tree as well.

**Scala** - This is the choice I would make if I was in your shoes.  You seem to not want to learn a new language, but Scala is a very easy transition from Java.  You can write very java-like code at first, and slowly adopt more functional idioms.  The Java <-> Scala interop is excellent in both directions as well.

**Clojure** - As much as I love Clojure, its tough to recommend in this particular instance due to the radically different syntax and steep learning curve for a java developer.

Comment: thanks. It's not that I'm not happy with any of them, just that I'm unfamiliar with them and unfortunately I don't have much time to make an informed decision on my own (hence this question). In general I don't mind learning a new language but it imposes a constraint on anyone maintaining / reviewing my code. I think I'm leaning towards Scala as well; I have "Programming in Scala" on my shelf, just that I can never seem to get the syntax right to actually use it.

Comment: @Jason S: I think investing in Scala would be well worth the effort.  Its a great language.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Google's guava-libraries may be of some use:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained

Answer (score 0):

Scala

> *You can call the methods of either language from methods in the other one*

http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time making the Clojure persistent/immutable data-structures work in Java, with sensible constructors and generics as part of [Pure4J](https://github.com/robmoffat/pure4j).

This also includes `@ImmutableValue` class for ensuring that not only are the collections immutable, but the values you put in them are immutable too.

Hope this helps.